# Split string and keep new lines

Tags: javascript, regex, photoshop-script

I'm trying to split a string ultimately into a 2D array with a semi colon as a delimiter.

```
var str = "2;poisson
            poisson
           3; Fromage
           6;Monique"
```

to

```
var arr = [2, "poisson
               poisson"],
          [3," Fromage"],
          [6,"Monique"]
```

The array is in the format

```
[int, string that may start with white space and may end with possible new lines]
```

The first step would be via regex. However, using `(\d+\;\s?)(.)+` doesn't grab lines with a new line. [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/aLvoAL/1).

I'm a little confused as to how to proceed as the newlines/carriage returns are important and I don't want to lose them. My RegEx Fu is weak today.

Comment: Is there a specific reason for using regex here? (e.g. why not just use `str.split(';')` which gives `['2', 'poisson\n            poisson\n           3', ' Fromage\n           6', 'Monique']` ?

Comment: ah nevermind just noticed the nuances with `\n` in your input/output

Comment: @akash the clue is in the title :)

Comment: split does keep new lines :)

Answer (score 2):

With Javascript, you could use 2 capture groups:

```
\b(\d+);([^]+?)(?=\n\s*\d+;|$)
```

The pattern matches:

- `\b` A word boundary
- `(\d+);` Capture **group 1**, capture 1+ digits followed by matching `;`
- `(` Capture **group 2**

  - `[^]+?` Match 1+ times any character including newlines
- `)` Close group
- `(?=` Positive lookahead, assert what to the right is

  - `\n\s*\d+;|$` Match either a newline followed by optional whitspace chars and the first pattern, or the end of the string
- `)` Close lookahead

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/5QMisA/1)

```js
const str = `2;poisson
            poisson
           3; Fromage
           6;Monique`;


const regex = /\b(\d+);([^]+?)(?=\n\s*\d+;|$)/g;
console.log(Array.from(str.matchAll(regex), m => [m[1], m[2]]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a short and sweet solution to get the result with two nested `.split()`:

```js
const str = `2;poisson
    poisson
3; Fromage
6;Monique`;
let result = str.split(/\n(?! )/).map(line => line.split(/;/));
console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
```

Output:

```
[["2","poisson\n    poisson"],["3"," Fromage"],["6","Monique"]]
```

Explanation of the first split regex:

- `\n` -- newline (possibly change to `[\r\n]+` to support Windows newlines
- `(?! )` -- negative lookahead for space

Comment: I found out, adding to my confusion, that Photoshop uses **\r** for new line text breaks!

Comment: @GhoulFool: yup, and `[\r\n]+` will take care of that